# java.io.IOException: Invalid argument and Too many open files

Tags: java, exception, io

I use library which download torrents. But today some error happened (log):
`Could not create temp files
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:261)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not create temp files
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:261)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not create temp files
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:261)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not create temp files
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:261)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not create temp files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/TorrentStealer/downloads/MAME - Update ROMs (v0.141 to v0.141u2)/lah_l104.zip (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:212)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:260)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not create temp files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/TorrentStealer/downloads/Degrassi.Junior.High.S01-S03.INTERNAL.DVDRip.XviD-FFNDVD/Degrassi.Junior.High.S01.INTERNAL.DVDRip.XviD-FFNDVDDegrassi.Junior.High.S01E10.INTERNAL.DVDRip.XviD-FFNDVDdegrassi.junior.high.s01e10.internal.dvdrip.xvid-ffndvd.r10 (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:212)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:260)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not create temp files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/TorrentStealer/downloads/MAME - Update ROMs (v0.141 to v0.141u2)/lah_l108.zip (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:212)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.checkTempFiles(DownloadManager.java:260)
    at jBittorrentAPI.DownloadManager.(DownloadManager.java:108)
    at torrentstealer.DownloadTorrent.run(DownloadTorrent.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`

And so on, log continues. I found that this file exists and here is a part of code where error happens:
    `/**
     * Check the existence of the files specified in the torrent and if necessary,
     * create them
     *
     * @return int
     * @todo Should return an integer representing some error message...
     */
    public synchronized int checkTempFiles() {
        String saveas = Constants.SAVEPATH; // Should be configurable
        if (this.nbOfFiles > 1)
            saveas += this.torrent.saveAs + "/";
        else
        {
            this.torrent.saveAs = this.torrent.name.get(0).toString();
        }
        new File(saveas).mkdirs();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nbOfFiles; i++) {
            File temp = new File(saveas + ((String) (this.torrent.name.get(i))));
            try {
                this.output_files[i] = new RandomAccessFile(temp, "rw");
                this.output_files[i].setLength((Integer)this.torrent.length.get(
                        i));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Could not create temp files");
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }`
Which called here:
        `// запуск закачки
        dm.startListening(49152, 65535);
        dm.startTrackerUpdate();`

```
    while(true)
    {
        if(dm.isComplete())
        {
            break;
        }

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DownloadTorrent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    dm.stopTrackerUpdate();
    dm.closeTempFiles();</code></pre>
```

And upper code called here:

        ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

for(String torrentFile : torrentFiles)
    {
        ex.submit(new DownloadTorrent("/root/TorrentStealer/torrents/" + torrentFile));
    }

    // ожидание завершения потоков загрузки файлов торрентов
    ex.shutdown();

    try
    {
        ex.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex1)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
    }

    ex.shutdownNow();</code></pre>

Here is description of fixing «Too many open files»:
http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Too+Many+Open+Files

I set up 999999 max files, that fixed error for some time, then set up 9999999 for testing, not really works, all the time error happens. There can't be 9999999 opened files at the one moment after running when the server has been rebooted!

So men I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

Here is count of opened files when exceptions happened:
T217:~# lsof | wc -l
Result is: 2708

Comment: I don't know why you had to post all those repetitions of the same errors. Complete waste of bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace indicated error at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength() which accept a `long` data type. In your code you cast the result of `this.torrent.length.get(i)` to Integer.

What `does this.torrent.length.get(i)` return?

it could be some downsizing issue when you convert data from the return to Integer, probably returning negative number which caused `RandomAccessFile.setLength()` to error out.

Comment: Checked this.torrent.name.get(i), this is the variables value of one of the files: -16929275. The next length is okay everywhere. This is the code which parse torrent and sets the value: this.torrent.length.add(((Long) ((Map) multFiles.get(i)).get("length")).intValue()); Also whats the problem with many opened files?

Comment: Oh yes, the length when setLength happens always signed. And when «many files» exception happens always unsigned and correct.

Comment: Cast to Long fixes first troubles. But what to do with «many open files»?

Comment: This is current log of exceptions: http://pastebin.com/XDY1diiz. Often Length is 15000000 is this also correct?

Comment: Okay, I think problem is done.

    ulimit -n 65535

In .bashrc fixes that problem.
But there is some problems with program, craches without exceptions. Will debug it.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
```

You are passing a negative value. Cast the value to a long not an Integer.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/TorrentStealer/downloads/MAME - Update ROMs (v0.141 to v0.141u2)/lah_l104.zip (Too many open files)
```

You aren't closing your files. Every resource you open that needs closing must be closed, in a finally block to ensure there is no escape.